# Create and add new page to asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on an ASP.NET `Web Application`. There is an Admin page and when administrator of the site adds a new entity, my web app, creates a new .aspx page using a template page. For examples it the new customer ID is 47, my web app creates 3 pages: `Customer47.aspx`, `Customer47.aspx.cs` and `Customer47.aspx.designer.cs`

At some point, the site visitor navigate to the created page, but the visitor gets error message:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyNamespace.Customer47'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Customer47.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Customer47" %>
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:  <%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace.DataModel" %>
>
> Source File:  /WebContents/Customer/47/Customer47.aspx    Line:  1

There is no error on generated pages because if I include those pages in Web Application and compile, the page will work.

I thought if I change Web Application to Web Site, I will solve the problem, but I prefer to not to do that.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: "creates a new .aspx page using a template page." - oh dear lord!

Comment: I have good reason for doing that.

Comment: What could possibly justify runtime code-generation in that particular way? This sounds like an incredibly bad system architecture and your post fails to provide any justification for this.